# How to move a class attribute in html element using javascript or jquery in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a menu selection on my web page using `<ul>` html tag, it has three `<li>` tags and on the list item it has an `<a>` tag. For the first load of the page I have written one of the list item tag with the class attribute. Now I want to move that class attribute from the first list item tag to the second list item tag when I click the second anchor tag and also goes for the third list item tag. My question is how will I do that in ASP .NET MVC 3 using plain JavaScript or with jQuery?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item">@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "ContactUs", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#menu li').click(function(){
    $('.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
    $(this).addClass('current_page_item');
})
```

Javascript is a little more verbose, but same idea:

```
var listnodes = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < listnodes.length; i++){
    listnodes[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        var listnodes = document.getElementsByClassName("current_page_item");
        for(var i = 0; i < listnodes.length; i++){
            listnodes[i].className = "";// this is not quite the same as removeClass
        }
        this.className = "current_page_item";
    });
}
```

The inner loop is unnecessary, since there's only one list item with that class at any given time, but I wanted to replicate the jQuery logic as far as possible.

Comment: Hi Asad, thank you for the helpful code you have provided it works fine but I had a problem when the page is redirected because the class does not retain in the <li> tag of the current page that was redirected by the anchor tag. Is there a way to retain that class in the jquery or javascript?

Comment: The state of the DOM is not maintained once the page is refreshed, unfortunately.